# Merge two HTML tables using Javascript Objects as data feed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

I am going to have multiple arrays of arrays and I want to make objects from the array and then merge it into one table.  I already did that, however I need help using the object to make one larger table?

If a key exists in one object but not the others the value can just be blank for the object the key doesnt exist.  I am able to make multiple different tables but how can I merge them to make the table one larger one?

```js
var data  =[["default_PROJECT","Allow","Connect","Allow","AddComment","Allow","Write",
"Allow","ViewComments","Allow","ExportData","Allow","ExportImage","Allow","ViewUnderlyingData","Allow","Read","Allow","ShareView","Allow","Filter"],
["Allow","ExportImage","Allow","Write","Allow","ViewComments",
"Allow","ShareView","Allow","Filter","Allow","ExportData","Allow","Connect","Allow",
"Read","Allow","ViewUnderlyingData","Allow","AddComment","Allow","ViewComments","Deny","ExportData","Allow",
"AddComment","Deny","Write","Allow","Read","Deny","ExportXml","Deny","ShareView","Allow","Connect","Allow","ChangeHierarchy","Allow",
"WebAuthoring","Deny","ViewUnderlyingData","Deny","Filter","Deny","ExportImage"]];
      var result = [];
   for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
     var list = data[i];
     
     result[i] = { name: list[0] };

    for (var j = list.length - 1; j >= 1; j = j - 2) {
       var key = list[j];
       var value = list[j - 1];
       if( result[i][key] !== "Deny" ) {
           result[i][key] = value;
       }
   }
   }
   console.log(result);
   var resultElement = document.getElementById('result1');
   var tpl = '';
   for(var t = 0, tLen = result.length; t < tLen; t++) {
     var item = result[t];
     
     tpl+= '<table align=center style="width:25%;">' +
       '<thead>' +
         '<tr><td colspan="2">Project: ' + item.name + '</td></tr>' +
         '<tr><th>Permission</th><th>Value</th></tr>' +
         '</thead>' +
       '<tbody>'
     ;
     
     for(var key in item) {
       if(!item.hasOwnProperty(key) || key === 'name') { continue; }
       if(item[key] == "Allow"){
        tpl += '<tr style="background-color:greenyellow;"><td>'+ key +'</td><td>'+ item[key] +'</td></tr>';   
       }
       else{
        tpl += '<tr style="background-color:red;"><td>'+ key +'</td><td>'+ item[key] +'</td></tr>';   
       }
     }
   }
   resultElement.innerHTML = tpl;
```

```css
table { text-align: left; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px; border-collapse: collapse;}
td, th { width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; line-height: 1; padding:2px 10px;}
[colspan="2"] { color: blue; font-weight: bolder;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/h2s17hac/

Comment: Can you create another jsfiddle with an HTML mockup of your *desired* outcome. Right now, it's unclear exactly what you want that final merged table to look like.

Comment: @AndyNoelker Yes sorry was working on the fiddle and updating.. http://jsfiddle.net/h2s17hac/4/

Comment: @AndyNoelker I was also trying to sort the keys of each object to get the keys to line up with each other, thats what I really want.

Comment: I took at a stab at what I think you want. Let me know if that is not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This merges the two tables.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pofud9ks/)

```js
var data  =[["default_PROJECT","Allow","Connect","Allow","AddComment","Allow","Write",
"Allow","ViewComments","Allow","ExportData","Allow","ExportImage","Allow","ViewUnderlyingData","Allow","Read","Allow","ShareView","Allow","Filter"],
["test_PROJECT", "Allow","ExportImage","Allow","Write","Allow","ViewComments",
"Allow","ShareView","Allow","Filter","Allow","ExportData","Allow","Connect","Allow",
"Read","Allow","ViewUnderlyingData","Allow","AddComment","Allow","ViewComments","Deny","ExportData","Allow",
"AddComment","Deny","Write","Allow","Read","Deny","ExportXml","Deny","ShareView","Allow","Connect","Allow","ChangeHierarchy","Allow",
"WebAuthoring","Deny","ViewUnderlyingData","Deny","Filter","Deny","ExportImage"]];

function makeObjects(data){
       result = [];
       for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
      var list = data[i];
      result[i] = { Name: list[0] };
     for (var j = list.length - 1; j >= 1; j = j - 2) {
        var key = list[j];
        var value = list[j - 1];
        if( result[i][key] !== "Deny" ) {
            result[i][key] = value;
        }
    }
  }
    return result;
}

function sortObject(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce(function (result, key) {
        result[key] = obj[key];
        return result;
    }, {});
}

function getKeys(data){
    var keys = [];
   for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
       key = Object.keys(data[i]);
      for(j =0; j<key.length; j++){
          if(keys.indexOf(key[j]) == -1){
           keys.push(key[j]);   
          }
       }
   }
    return keys;
}

function addMissingKeys(keys, data){
    var filtData = [];
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        for(j=0; j<keys.length; j++){
         if(data[i][keys[j]] == undefined){
          data[i][keys[j]] = "";  
         }
        }
    }
    for(num=0; num<data.length; num++){
        filtData.push(sortObject(data[num]));
    }
 return filtData;
}

var dataa = makeObjects(data);
var keys = getKeys(dataa);
var filtData = addMissingKeys(keys, dataa);
console.log(filtData);
    var resultElement = document.getElementById('result1');
    var tpl = '<table align=center style="width:75%;">';
    for(var t = 0, tLen = filtData.length; t < tLen; t++) {
      var item = filtData[t];
                 
      tpl+= '<tr><td>' + item.Name + '</td>';
      
      for(var key in item) {
        if(!item.hasOwnProperty(key) || key === 'Name') { continue; }
                   if(item[key] != "") {
                     if(item[key] == "Allow"){
                         tpl += '<td style="background-color:greenyellow;">'+ key +':<br>'+ item[key] +'</td>';   
                     }
                     else{
                         tpl += '<td style="background-color:red;">'+ key +':<br>'+ item[key] +'</td>';   
                     }
                   } else {
                     tpl += '<td></td>';
                   }
                 
      }
               tpl += '</tr>';
    }
             tpl += '</table>';
    resultElement.innerHTML = tpl;
```

```css
table { text-align: left; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px; border-collapse: collapse;}
td, th { width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; line-height: 1; padding:2px 10px;}
[colspan="2"] { color: blue; font-weight: bolder;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Ehhh, I wanted to make it one table, see the bottom.  Where there is a row for each project then the permissions.  I need they keys to line up, and if there is no key then the cell should be blank?

Comment: Ahh okay now I understand what you mean. Give me a bit and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  I am working on another fiddle too to help improve it.  Ill share when I am done.

Comment: this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/h2s17hac/5/   I changed it so for each object I sorted it and then added keys as empty values if the object didnt have that key.  This way itll be easier to store in table format.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that second fiddle was definitely the right direction to head. I edited my answer and it now works as you wanted.